# JavaScript SDK for Facebook not getting the login status

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using the below code, but it always says not logged in (even if I have logged in
status). How can I fix this problem?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({appId:"my appid",
             status: true,
             cookie: true,
             logging:false,
             xfbml: true,
             oauth:true});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        alert ("here11");
        if (response.session) {
            alert ("already logged in");
        }
        else {
            alert ("not logged in");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you logging in? I suspect you are going to `facebook.com` to login and then expecting this to say you are logged in? This will not work. You have to initiate a session on your own domain using the [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). Try this:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            FB.logout(function(response) {
              console.log('Logged out.');
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
    }
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

And also, check [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/).

Comment: My goal is to get whether the user liked the page or not without permissions prompts
if i use FB.login, it always ask the permission , how we can avoid the permission promt for fangating using javascript SDK

Comment: you need permission in order to get any information about someone. like their facebook id and their likes. There is no way to do this without at least basic permissions.